# Emacs auto-complete

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

since I can't get `CEDET` to work for automatic code-completion (aka intelli-sense in the MS-world), after trying several times (no, it's just not working!), I've decided to use `auto-complete`, which works "quite fine" for me.

Unfortunately, `auto-complete` has an annoying behaviour when it comes to quit the `imenu` with its suggestions.

1. `auto-complete` starts `imenu`, no matter how many suggestions it has. So, if there's only one suggestion, the menu appears.
   1.
2. To exit the `imenu`, I have to use the `LEFT` or `RIGHT` keys in order to make the menu disappear. `ESC-ESC-ESC` does not have any effect.

Is there any way, to modify these two behaviors?

Here's an excerpt of my `.emacs` file showing the `auto-complete` relevant stuff:

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
(setq ac-delay 0.5) ;; eclipse uses 500ms
```

Kind regards,
mefiX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Stop autocompleting' can be set by adding the following to your .emacs:

```
(define-key ac-completing-map "\ESC/" 'ac-stop)
```

...or alternatively you can use C-g as the default Emacs StopSomething command :)

As for showing the completion in a menu when there's only one candidate, I'm not really sure what other behaviour you'd want?

Comment: I presume when there is only one candidate, the desired behavior would be to just insert that candidate. Some autocomplete engines do this even with a selection of candidates; they will cycle through all available candidates with successive hotkey activation.

Comment: Thank you, David Miller. Unfortunately, the key-assignment doesn't work in my case and I don't know why. For example, I'm editing my .emacs-file, where ac works very well. So I type "(def" and imenu pops up with (1+) suggestions (including "(defun"). When I hit "ESC", nothing happens. I've evaluated the "define-key" previously, of course. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, after some trying, I figured out that pressing AND holding escape is what "\ESC/" stands for, which was not what I wanted. After some research, I found out that `(define-key ac-completing-map "\e" 'ac-stop)` does the trick!